# R - reduce multilevel list and add id variable at each step

Tags: r, list

Let's say that you have a list in R named `Weather` which is structured like this:

```
 - Winter
   - Europe
        - Rainfall
        - Temperature
   - Asia
        - Rainfall
        - Temperature
   - Africa
        - Rainfall
        - Temperature
 - Summer
   - Europe
        - Rainfall
        - Temperature
   - Asia
        - Rainfall
        - Temperature
   - Africa
        - Rainfall
        - Temperature
```

Each of the objects stored in `Rainfall` or `Temperature` is a data frame which contains two variables: `Date` and `Temp` in case of `Temperature` and `Date` and `Rain` in the case of `Rainfall`.

I want to turn this list of lists into a data frame which has the following variables: `Date`, `Temp`, `Rain`, `Continent`, `Season`.

I don't understand how can I automatically add the ID variable to the lower levels of the list, pulling the names from the lower levels of the list. For now I have to do it manually like this:

```
Weather$Winter$Europe$Rainfall$Continent <- "Europe"
Weather$Winter$Europe$Temperature$Continent <- "Europe"
Weather$Winter$Asia$Rainfall$Continent <- "Asia"
Weather$Winter$Asia$Temperature$Continent <- "Asia"
Weather$Winter$Africa$Rainfall$Continent <- "Africa"
Weather$Winter$Africa$Temperature$Continent <- "Africa"
Weather$Summer$Europe$Rainfall$Continent <- "Europe"
Weather$Summer$Europe$Temperature$Continent <- "Europe"
Weather$Summer$Asia$Rainfall$Continent <- "Asia"
Weather$Summer$Asia$Temperature$Continent <- "Asia"
Weather$Summer$Africa$Rainfall$Continent <- "Africa"
Weather$Summer$Africa$Temperature$Continent <- "Africa"
```

Then I use `map_depth` and `reduce` to join the lists. After that, I have to repeat this process to manually add the `Season` variable, and only then am I able to reduce all the data frames into a single one.

I am looking for a method that would allow me to automatically create the ID variables (`Continent`, `Season`), which are actually pulled from list names, while reducing the list.

Comment: Consider providing sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a starting point:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- list(
  Winter = list(
    Europe = list(
      Rainfall = data.frame(Date = c("2022-06-01", "2022-06-02", "2022-06-03"), Rain = c(20, 10, 15)),
      Temperature = data.frame(Date = c("2022-06-01", "2022-06-02", "2022-06-03"), Temp = c(0, 0.5, 0.8))
    ),
    Asia = list(
      Rainfall = data.frame(Date = c("2022-06-01", "2022-06-02", "2022-06-03"), Rain = c(30, 35, 34)),
      Temperature = data.frame(Date = c("2022-06-01", "2022-06-02", "2022-06-03"), Temp = c(0, 0, 0.1))
    )
  )
)
data
#> $Winter
#> $Winter$Europe
#> $Winter$Europe$Rainfall
#>         Date Rain
#> 1 2022-06-01   20
#> 2 2022-06-02   10
#> 3 2022-06-03   15
#> 
#> $Winter$Europe$Temperature
#>         Date Temp
#> 1 2022-06-01  0.0
#> 2 2022-06-02  0.5
#> 3 2022-06-03  0.8
#> 
#> 
#> $Winter$Asia
#> $Winter$Asia$Rainfall
#>         Date Rain
#> 1 2022-06-01   30
#> 2 2022-06-02   35
#> 3 2022-06-03   34
#> 
#> $Winter$Asia$Temperature
#>         Date Temp
#> 1 2022-06-01  0.0
#> 2 2022-06-02  0.0
#> 3 2022-06-03  0.1

data %>%
  rapply(as.list) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  separate(name, into = c("Season", "Continent", "table", "name"), sep = "[.]") %>%
  mutate(name = name %>% str_remove("[0-9]+$")) %>%
  select(-table) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(Date) %>%
  unnest(Rain) %>%
  unnest(Temp)
#> # A tibble: 108 × 5
#>    Season Continent Date       Rain  Temp 
#>    <chr>  <chr>     <chr>      <chr> <chr>
#>  1 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 20    0    
#>  2 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 20    0.5  
#>  3 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 20    0.8  
#>  4 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 10    0    
#>  5 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 10    0.5  
#>  6 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 10    0.8  
#>  7 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 15    0    
#>  8 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 15    0.5  
#>  9 Winter Europe    2022-06-01 15    0.8  
#> 10 Winter Europe    2022-06-02 20    0    
#> # … with 98 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>